# Не работает цикл при создании словаря

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

class VK:

    def __init__(self, token, v):
        self.token = token
        self.v = v


    def get_photo(self):

        token = '958eb5d439726565e9333aa30e50e0f937ee432e927f0dbd541c541887d919a7c56f95c04217915c32008'
        url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get'
        params = {
                'owner_id': 552934290,
                'album_id': 'profile',
                'extended': 1,
                'photo_sizes': 0,
                'access_token': token,
                'v': 5.131
        }
        r = requests.get(url, params=params)
        # pprint(r.json()['response']['items'])
        for i in r.json()['response']['items']:
            self.y = (i['likes']['count'])
            for j in r.json()['response']['items']:
               self.j = j

    def create_dict(self):

       dct = {self.y: self.j}
       pprint(dct)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vk = VK('958eb5d439726565e9333aa30e50e0f937ee432e927f0dbd541c541887d919a7c56f95c04217915c32008', 5.131)
    vk.get_photo()
    vk.create_dict()
```

Мой вопрос. В функции get_photo я получаю сами фото и кол-во лайков, все через цикл. Далее я создаю функию create_dict и хочу создать словарь где ключами будут лайки этого фото, а значением все данные в том числе урлы. Но вот в чем дело при создании словаря цикл не запускается как будто и выдает всего один словарь с данным фото, а должен перечислить все. Почему так ?

Comment: почему должен все? при создании словаря цикл не запускается, потому что при создании словаря нет ни одной строчки про цикл

Comment: НО ведь я же беру переменные из get_photo и там цикл есть, я полагаю что эти переменные обработаны циклом. И их я просто вставляю в словарь. Если это не так,  подскажите как это тогда сделать. Без новой функции для создания словаря у меня не выходит сделать так как необходимо словарь в той последовательности как я хочу либо ключи неверные, либо значения. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: обработаны циклом, а в цикле каждое предыдущее значение заменяется следующим, остается только самое последнее. перенесите цикл в создание словаря

Comment: Получилось, но мы вернулись к тому что я говорил ранее. Ключи верные, а значения не верны

Comment: посмотрите еще раз, как у вас формируются ключ и значение словаря. Они вообще никак не связаны